# Сортировка по нескольким параметрам не срабатывает

Tags: java, сортировка, lambda

```
List<ObjectComposition> objComposition = objectsComposition.stream()
                .sorted((oc1, oc2) -> {
                    return  Integer.parseInt(oc1.getNumberAccordingToPlan().replaceAll("\\D+", "")) -
                            Integer.parseInt(oc2.getNumberAccordingToPlan().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
                })
                .sorted((oc1, oc2) -> {
                    return  Integer.parseInt(oc1.getGroupNumber().replaceAll("\\D+", "")) -
                            Integer.parseInt(oc2.getGroupNumber().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Ну должно же отсортировать нормально - по номеру и по группе. Что бы в группе были значения в порядке возрастания. Получается:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Не понимаю, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Проблема воспроизводиться при сортировке только по `numberAccordingToPlan`? На двух объектах? Если да, то можете подготовить [воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ваш `stream` до этого места включительно будет отсортирован по `numberAccordingToPlan`

```
objectsComposition.stream()
            .sorted((oc1, oc2) -> {
                return  Integer.parseInt(oc1.getNumberAccordingToPlan().replaceAll("\\D+", "")) -
                        Integer.parseInt(oc2.getNumberAccordingToPlan().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
            }) 
...
...
```

а с этого:

```
...
...
.sorted((oc1, oc2) -> {
                return  Integer.parseInt(oc1.getGroupNumber().replaceAll("\\D+", "")) -
                        Integer.parseInt(oc2.getGroupNumber().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
            })
```

он будет отсортирован уже только по `groupNumber`

Чтобы добиться того, чего вам нужно, нужно использовать один компаратор:

```
List<ObjectComposition> objComposition = objectsComposition.stream()
            .sorted((oc1, oc2) -> {
                int cmp = Integer.parseInt(oc1.getNumberAccordingToPlan().replaceAll("\\D+", "")) -
                        Integer.parseInt(oc2.getNumberAccordingToPlan().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
                if(cmp == 0){
                    cmp = Integer.parseInt(oc1.getGroupNumber().replaceAll("\\D+", "")) -
                            Integer.parseInt(oc2.getGroupNumber().replaceAll("\\D+", ""));
                }
                return cmp;
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Если вам нужно чтобы первым ключом сортировки было поле `groupNumber`, поменяйте порядок сравнения в этом компараторе.

Comment: Не помогает. Проблема та же, что на картинке - 1 оказывается в конце группы В-1...

Comment: @Артём, не может быть такого. Вы что-то не так сделали. Почему у вас вообще в выводе `groundType`, а в коде `groupNumber`? Это одно и то же?

Comment: Рукалицо. Моя вина. Не понимаю как я это не заметил. Да, это разные поля. Спасибо. З.Ы. Сортировка .sorted((oc1, oc2) -> {...}).sorted((oc1, oc2) -> {...}) сортирует правильно.

Comment: @Артём-.....-...-.-, если ответ вам помог, то вы можете отметить его верным)

Comment: @iksuy С разными данными - с разным количеством групп и номеров сортировка идет верно. Выходит верный ответ. Почему не правильно?

Comment: @Артём, да, действительно всё корректно работает, я уже понял :)